# The value is entered in the table, but ajax message does not return PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to register multiple values ​​based on the amount of parcels reported by the form.
I need the month of the expiration date to add +1 in each record.
The code below is entering the table, and the month of the due date is being incremented on each record ... However, the success message does not return. Returns only when I remove the line that adds a month to the due date.

Here is part of the code "ajax/register-expense.php":

```
$response["status"] = "";
$response["html"] = "";
// If there is no error
if (!isset($error)) {
   // Resetting $paid Variable Value
   $paid = (!empty($paid)) ? "Yes" : "No";

   $sql = "INSERT INTO expenses (expense_value, due_date, paid, paid_date, important, repeat_type, plots, comments, id_usuario, id_expense_type, id_paid_type) VALUES ";
   $insertQuery = array();
   $insertData = array();
   $n = 0;
   while ($n < $plots) {
      $due_date = $due_date;
      $insertQuery[] = "(:expense_value".$n.", :due_date".$n.", :paid".$n.", :paid_date".$n.", :important".$n.", :repeat_type".$n.", :plots".$n.", :comments".$n.", :id_usuario".$n.", :id_expense_type".$n.", :id_paid_type".$n.")";
      $insertData["expense_value".$n]   = $expense_value;
      $insertData["due_date".$n]        = $due_date;
      $insertData["paid".$n]            = $paid;
      $insertData["paid_date".$n]       = $paid_date;
      $insertData["important".$n]       = $important;
      $insertData["repeat_type".$n]     = $repeat_type;
      $insertData["plots".$n]           = $plots;
      $insertData["comments".$n]        = $comments;
      $insertData["id_user".$n]         = $id_logged;
      $insertData["id_expense_type".$n] = $id_expense_type;
      $insertData["id_paid_type".$n]    = $id_paid_type;
      $due_date = date("Y-m-d",(strtotime('next month',strtotime(date($due_date)))));
      $n++;
   }

   try {
      $pdo = openConn();
      if (!empty($insertQuery)) {
          $sql .= implode(", ", $insertQuery);
          $insert = $pdo->prepare($sql);
          $insert->execute($insertData);

          if($insert) {
             // Success message
             $response["html"] = "Expense has been successfully registered!";
          }
      $response["status"] = "success";
      }
      // Close conn
      $pdo = null;
   } catch (PDOException $e) {
      // Error message
   }
} else {
   foreach($error as $erro) {
       $response["html"] .= $erro . "<br>";
   }
   $response["status"] = "error";
}
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Ajax form:

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
      $("#att_data").attr("disabled", true);

      var parameters = $(form).serialize();
      var modalAjax = $("#modalAjaxMessage");
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "ajax/register-expense.php",
          dataType: "json",
          data: parameters,
          beforeSend: function(object){
              modalAjax.find(".modal-body").html("Loading...");
          },
          success: function(data){
          modalAjax.modal("show").find(".modal-body").html(data.html);
              setTimeout(function() {
                 modalAjax.modal("hide");
              }, 2500);
              if (data.status == "success") {
                  clear_validations_form(form);
              }
              $("#att_data").attr("disabled", false);
          }
      });
      return false;
}
```

Comment: [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: I'm from Brazil, but the code is in English and it's okay to have English support...

Comment: This is the wrong approach to inserting data. Make one prepared statement with placeholder values and execute it a number of times with different data bound on each iteration. You're over-complicating this. If you need the insert to be atomic, use a transaction around it.

Comment: Please see my comment below.

Comment: I solved it! I was forgetting to add: date_default_timezone_set("America/Sao_Paulo");

Answer (score 0):

I did this in the following way:

```
  $n = 0;
  while ($n < $plots) {
     $inserir = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO expenses (expense_value, due_date, paid, paid_date, important, repeat_type, plots, comments, id_user, id_expense_type, id_paid_type) VALUES(:expense_value".$n.", :due_date".$n.", :paid".$n.", :paid_date".$n.", :important".$n.", :repeat_type".$n.", :plots".$n.", :comments".$n.", :id_user".$n.", :id_expense_type".$n.", :id_paid_type".$n.")");
     $inserir->execute(array(
          ":expense_value".$n   => $expense_value,
          ":due_date".$n        => $due_date,
          ":paid".$n            => $paid,
          ":paid_date".$n       => $paid_date,
          ":important".$n       => $important,
          ":repeat_type".$n     => $repeat_type,
          ":plots".$n           => $plots,
          ":comments".$n        => $comments,
          ":id_user".$n         => $id_user,
          ":id_expense_type".$n => $id_expense_type,
          ":id_paid_type".$n    => $id_paid_type
     ));
     $due_date = date("Y-m-d",(strtotime('next month',strtotime(date($due_date)))));
     $n++;
  }
```

It still returns the success message only when I remove the variable that increases the date.

Comment: The `$n` in this can be factored out to no ill-effect, and if you do that you can call `prepare()` once and `execute()` as many times as necessary. This is significantly more efficient when inserting large amounts of data.